# Power BI DAX function more than 2 or conditon

Tags: powerbi

I am creating roles in power BI and filtering the table by principle code -

For example role1 - can only see data of CKBD, CKRANP, DA principle for that I am using dax function -

```
OR([principlecode] = "CKB" ||  [principlecode] = "CKBD"|| [principlecode] = "DA")
```

But its say or condition can have only 2 argument, there is any way of doing this?

Comment: ok just needed remove or

Answer (score 9):

For clarity, DAX offers two options for logical ORs (as well as logical ANDs):

1. The OR function (as well as AND function)
2. The binary || operator (as well as binary && operator)

**The OR function** accepts exactly two arguments to perform the logical OR:

```
OR([principlecode]="CKB", [principlecode]="CKBD"])
```

To do this with your example, you must nest the OR statements because DAX doesn't provide the function with more than 2 parameters:

```
OR(OR([principlecode]="CKB", [principlecode]="CKBD"]),[principlecode] = "DA")
```

Pretty ugly, IMO. Note that the AND operator has the same challenge:

```
AND(AND(first_boolean, second_boolean), third_boolean)
```

**On the other hand, the binary operator** || performs a logical OR across the operands, and allows the statement to be chained (as you point out in your own answer):

```
[principlecode] = "CKB" ||  [principlecode] = "CKBD"|| [principlecode] = "DA"
```

Similarly, for logical AND:

```
first_boolean && second_boolean && third_boolean
```

I don't believe there are any performance cost differences between the two methods.

Answer (score 1):

ok just needed remove or

```
([principlecode] = "CKB" ||  [principlecode] = "CKBD"|| [principlecode] = "DA")
```